# Managing visual assets on xcode (reference, copy or both)?

Tags: ios, xcode, image, macos, assets

Good evening overflowers,
I was wondering what would be the best way to manage assets (visual, sound, etc.) in xcode for ios or mac os projects.

I am currently working on a project that the image files change all the time (design is under construction still) and I would like to know the best way to keep all the files updated while having them in the project's directory.

So for instance I have a file named "ic_action_gray_button@2x.png" This button changes on the design but still has the same name. Is there a magical way to mirror the changes and have it also under source control without spending time finding and replacing the file all the time?

It is something easy when it comes to 50 assets but when these assets become 100 or 500  then, it becomes difficult to keep up with the changes.

Any tutorial or any guide to help me through this process?

If my question is not clear, be easy on me, I am not a native English speaker :)

Kind Regards,

Sonic555gr

Comment: +1 for using **Good evening overflowers**

Comment: What do you mean by "mirror the changes"? Please explain the issue in more detail.

Comment: Sorry for the poor description. I mean that If I reference the design folder which is on another github repo, then when I push changes to my repo the files referenced will not be transfered. If I copy the files to my project, then when something changes to the design repo, I will not get automatic updates for the changes. The main question is, Is there a magical way to keep the files update from the design folder by mirroring the changes automatically to my project Or I have to reimport the updated files?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a separate folder for your assets inside your project folder. Then you can drag your asset folder to your project in Xcode, select "Create folder references for any added folders" and uncheck "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)". This should serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is just to take the 100 - 150 or however many assets and paste them in Finder.

As long as the files have the same names, you are just doing an overwrite in Finder, inside the folder of your XCode project.

Any new images, you can add to XCode as usual, by drag & drop, then selecting copy and choosing the target. Any replacements can be done in Finder after that.

Git will also detect the file modifications and you can push the changes to your repo. For file/assets replacements, there is no need to do it through XCode and add the new images again.

If you are using asset catalogs for your images, its just a matter of replacing the files inside the specific folders, which is tedious, its then easier to just select them all inside XCode, delete them from the catalog, and from the project, and then just drag and drop them into the asset catalog again.